# Microk8s baremetal redundancy failover

Tags: kubernetes, failover, microk8s

I have a bare metal kubernetes cluster spanning over a cluster of raspberry pis where I am hosting some applications. And I want to test and setup an environment where if I "kill" any of the nodes anytime everything should still be up and available.

The applications running are build with .NET Core Orleans 7 which should work if pods die, so the application part I dont have to worry about that much.

But the kubernetes and network part is more difficult, so currently I have an nginx-ingress routing the traffic to my service which reaches the application. But, it is only running on the master node, so if I kill the master node, everything dies.
And also, I have a firewall rule that points direcly at the master node, so what I think I have the do is create some kind of loadbalancer which has its own ip and has a "pod" copy on all of the nodes but only one running at the time, and if the master dies, a new pod on a different node is getting started with the "same" ip as before.

Thanks in advance!

Best regards Max